# Prove that $\dim_\mathbb{C}(M)$ is finite for simple right $A$-module $M$ where $A$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and let $M$ be a simple right $A$-module. Show that $\dim_\mathbb{C}(M)$ is finite.

This is a part of practice question [Algebra I. Martin Isaacs 12.19] that I don't understand. Can anyone explain me why this is true?

Comment: Hint: If $m\in M$ is non-zero, the $\Bbb{C}$-linear mapping $a\mapsto a\cdot m$ from $A$ to $M$ is surjective.

Comment: Oh, $M$ was a *right* $A$-module. Make that $a\mapsto m\cdot a$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Since $M$ is simple, the submodule generated by $m$ which is the image of the map is equal to $M$ ifself. But $A$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{C}$, so is $M$. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. Well done! Feel free to write that up as an answer to get more feedback on the details.